# Unable to add images in the navigation bar when using split view controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

In split view controller, I am unable to add images in the navigation bar neither in the title not in the bar button. But, normally if I create view controller and embedded in navigation controller, I can add images to title view as well as bar button.

**Issue:**

Master view and Detail view. In Detail view I am adding images to title view. It is not working.

**Structure**

**splitViewController --> Navigation Controller --> Detail View Controller**

**splitViewController --> Navigation Controller --> Master View Controller**

**Coding**

In DetailVC.

```
func viewDidLoad()
{
super.viewDidLoad()
let image = UIImage(named: "logo")
navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: image)
}
```

Comment: Would the title change with the same method? Your code seems to be good. I'm thinking maybe you haven't setup the split view controller right.

Comment: Hi Peyman!!! I need to be image in title.

Comment: I understand, I just want to know if you're problem is with changing properties of navigationItem or changing titleView specifically.

Comment: Leave that splitVC. Normally we having VC embed with NC. Then, I can add image to titleView in NB with the above code. Now, Why I couldnt do if I add splitVC.